# Have "Where you'd 'not' like to work" an option in preferences?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

In your Jobs profile you can specify where you would like to work, which is great, but could there also be a way to negate this?

For example, if I were be willing to work anywhere in the US outside of California or New York, there's no way to explicitly specify that.

As far as I can tell they only way to achieve this currently is to specify every other state I would like to work, which isn't a great solution.

Comment: I've had several "We really like this job for you." emails for roles in London.   There is lots of work in London but there is no way I want to work there.  My "where you'd like to work" preferences have a forced inclusion of "United Kingdom" which I cannot remove.  I assume this is the reason for the spam